# What are some optimal Windows 7 settings for maximizing a graphics card benchmark test?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, benchmarking

I am using the HWBOT site to submit benchmarks. I have had some success with CPU benchmarking, achieving a hardware rank of #1 for my specific hardware in SuperPI 1M and #3 for SuperP! 32M.

However, graphics card performance is not going so well.
Remember that this is a rating for my specific hardware, so it really isn't a matter at all about which graphics card I have (I have a GTX 570M), since the benchmark tests are compared against other users with the same graphics card.

The important thing to note here, is that I am using complete standard stock cooling (It's a laptop anyway), and also that I am not doing any kind of overclocking.

So far I have:

- Closed all software programs
- Disabled all services possible that don't make my PC crash
- Disabled all Windows visual effects
- Cleared all Windows cache
- Installed the latest NVIDIA drivers (the newest Beta drivers)
- Even tried lowering the screen resolution to minimum (800 x 600)

I can't think of anything else I could do to improve my hardware score.
Using "Unigine Heaven" with 'Basic Preset (DX9)', I achieved a score of about 1270.

My first attempt was a score of 1230, and when I disabled visual effects and lowered the screen resolution, it increased my score by 40 points.

If anyone can give me more ideas to help improve my score, please do tell.

Comment: did you tweak it with things like rivatuner? do you have the v-lock off?  with some tuning software you can cheat the scores into oblivion, because things are not rendered the same. Not all updated drivers are "faster" some actually fix bugs :-) , there can also be alternative drivers, that are slower or faster depending. Besides overclocking, you can get surprising increases from raising the PCI clock rate, with the caveats, that it can unstable disk into corruption, and even damage your card in rare instances. A rise of 10%-12% wors most times.

Comment: All ways to cheat are illegal in HWBOT. What is rivatuner? What is v-lock? How do I raise the PCI clock rate, and how is that not considered overclocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lowering the resolution actually pushes more work onto the CPU.  That will not help your GPU scores. And any decent benchmark will run all configurations at a standard resolution so you can standardize the scores.

From the looks of it, that looks like you are doing what you need to.  At least if you are looking to compete in synthetic benchmarks.   There are other settings you maybe able to adjust by flashing the ROM, but that is really a matter of trial and error.